# Passing a variable in codeception through command prompt

Tags: codeception

As like we pass the browser name and other details from command prompt in codecetion, can we pass any variable which can be used within the script from command prompt?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: agreed with @Alexander : please revisit the question and elaborate further on it, with specific examples and use cases.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any way to do it in documentation and other feeds.

I add pull request for this ability [use params from console in tests](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/pull/3978)

When it will be merged in master you can run tests like this:

```
php codecept run -p "site-id: 123456, group: admin" -p "duty: free"
```

You can find more information in PR.